# How to resolve an uninstall window appear issue after restart the system?

Tags: c#

I have tried to install an exe developed using `Wix installer`. After installation completed, tried to restart the system. Following sample logic I used.

**Samples :**

```
        private void btn_RestartYes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RestartThreadFunction));
            thread.Start();
            this.Close();
            SyncBA.Model.Engine.Quit(0);

        }
        public void RestartThreadFunction()
        {
            try
            {
                Process.Start("shutdown", "/r");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SyncBA.Model.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Error, ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btn_RestartLater_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();

        }
                                  ( OR )


       private void btn_RestartYes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RestartThreadFunction();          

        }
        public void RestartThreadFunction()
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
                proc.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                proc.FileName = "cmd";
                proc.Arguments = "/C shutdown -f -r";
                Process.Start(proc);
                SyncBA.Model.Engine.Quit(0);
                this.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SyncBA.Model.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Error, ex.Message);
            }
        }
    private void btn_RestartLater_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();

    }
```

> Above logic is successfully working fine. After restarted the system "exe" uninstall window appear.

How to resolve an uninstall window appear issue after restart the system?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please tag only the appropriate language tag.